# Why can we set url for the repository in this way in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://mvn.xxxx.com/jcenter"
        }
    }
}
```

We can use this code to set the base URL of the repository, but I can't find a method called `url()` in the Gradle DSL Reference for [MavenArtifactRepository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/MavenArtifactRepository.html). How to explain it?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, there is the [`setUrl`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/MavenArtifactRepository.html#setUrl(java.lang.Object)) method in the `MavenArtifactRepository`.

So you can set a maven repository in this way:

```
   repositories {
                maven {
                   credentials {
                       username xxx
                       password xxx
                   }
                   url    'http://mymaven/xxxx/repositories/releases/'
                }
           }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I also want to know how this mapping is set up?

Comment: @MuziLee Not sure what you are asking with the comment. The mapping is a simple setter in java. With a property x, the mapping is with setX(), getX().

Comment: Then why "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0" mapped to `add()` method in [DependencyHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html)?